# Display parent table title field once then child records in groups

Tags: php, mysql, recordset

I am wanting to display lists of FAQs using 2 tables: faqset and faqs

For example:

**GENERAL FAQs** (faqset name)

Question 1
Answer 1

Question 2
Answer 2

Question 3
Answer 3

**PRE-SALE FAQs** (faqset name)

Question 4
Answer 4

Question 5
Answer 5

Question 6
Answer 6

I believe I have the query, but I want the title for each group to display just once, but it is displaying for each child, like this:

**General FAQs**

Question 1
Answer 1

**General FAQs**

Question 2
Answer 2

faqset fields are qsid and name

faqs fields are fid, question, answer, qgroup (=qsid from faqset), status, rank

Here is the query and code I have:

```js
<?
$query="SELECT faqset.*, faqs.* FROM faqset LEFT JOIN faqs ON faqset.qsid = faqs.qgroup WHERE faqs.status=1 ORDER BY faqset.name, faqs.rank, faqs.fid DESC";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
mysql_close();
?>

<?
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$qsid=mysql_result($result,$i,"faqset.qsid");
$setname=mysql_result($result,$i,"faqset.name");
$fid=mysql_result($result,$i,"faqs.fid");
$question=mysql_result($result,$i,"faqs.question");
$answer=mysql_result($result,$i,"faqs.answer");
?>
<? echo "$setname"; ?>

<div id="faqcontainer">
<div id="faq_<? echo "$fid"; ?>">
<? if (!empty($question)) {?><div id="question"><? echo "$question"; ?></div><?php } ?>
<? if (!empty($answer)) {?><div><br/><? echo "$answer"; ?></div><?php } ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>

<?
++$i;
} 


?>
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Update your code to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` first. `mysql_*` is deprecated and I refuse to help out with code that'll lead to serious problems sooner or later. Like SQL injection etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the current title to a var and only print it if not the same -

```
<?

$current_setname = "";

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
...[your code]...
?>

<? if($setname != $current_setname){
     echo $setname; 
     $current_setname = $setname;
   }

...[your code]...
?>
```